# How do you change node colours for ggdag plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, directed-acyclic-graphs

The [`ggdag` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdag/vignettes/intro-to-ggdag.html) allows you to create and plot DAGs in `R`.  Here is an example:

```
#Load libraries
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)

#Create and print a DAG
DAG <- dagify(y ~ x, x ~ a, a ~ y)
ggdag(DAG)
```

[image]

I would like to adjust this plot to colour some of the nodes (of my choice) in a different colour.  For example, suppose I want to colour node `y` in red.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the most flexibility out of `{ggdag}` by plotting directly with `{ggplot2}`. To colour your `y` node in another colour, add a new column to the tidy DAG and plot with the colour aesthetic:

```
#Load libraries
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)

DAG <- dagify(y ~ x, x ~ a, a ~ y) %>% 
  tidy_dagitty() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(colour = ifelse(name == "y", "Colour 1", "Colour 2"))

DAG %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    xend = xend,
    yend = yend
  )) +
  geom_dag_point(aes(colour = colour)) +
  geom_dag_edges() +
  geom_dag_text() +
  theme_dag()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Robert! Could you clarify how to change the color of the nodes (not only "y" but all nodes, e.g. "y" in red and everything else in black)? Would be great!