# ggdag colouring nodes a specific color

Tags: r, causality

I am currently experimenting with `ggdag` and I want to color the exposure, the outcome, and the rest of the nodes.

How can I make every node that's not an exposure or outcome the this hex color: #fcba03?

This is my working example code so far:

```
simple_dag <- ggdag::dagify(
  y ~ x + a + b,
  x ~ a + b,
  exposure = "x",
  outcome = "y"
)

dag_labels <- setNames(stringr::str_to_title(names(simple_dag)), names(simple_dag))
ggdag::label(simple_dag) <- dag_labels

ggdag::ggdag_status(simple_dag, 
             use_labels = "label", text = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441472/change-color-for-specific-nodes-in-ggdag/71441773#71441773 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```r
p <- ggdag::ggdag_status(simple_dag, 
                         use_labels = "label", text = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = 'none', color = 'none') 

p$layers[[3]]$mapping <- aes(colour = status)
p + scale_color_discrete(na.value = '#fcba03') +
    scale_fill_discrete(na.value = '#fcba03')
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but how do I get the labels to also be the same color?

Comment: More specifically.. I would like labels A and B to be yellow as well.

Comment: See my update @Eisen